# Can I throttling the CPU usage of NSOperation / Thread on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, cpu-usage, nsoperation

I have a data parse loop which cause heavy CPU load ,
on Dual Core iPhone is ok, but on old model iPhone the UI response will come slow or even no response for a while... (the operation not run on main thread)

Can I limit the CPU usage ? and how to ?

Comment: The answer of that question is about to update the UI during async task ? 
But in my situation, the data parse loop is a background task not related to the UI, and it keeps 100% CPU loading for a while that cause UI no response.

Answer (score 0):

NSOperations have a method `setThreadPriority:` that determines the priority of the operation in it's queue. The priority defaults to normal. Try setting your operations to the next-lower priority, NSOperationQueuePriorityLow. That will cause the operation to run at a lower priority than the main thread, and should make your UI much more responsive. As a result, of course, your task will take longer to complete.

(Edited to suggest using setThreadPriority instead of setQueuePriority)

Comment: Seems `setQueuePriority:` is just setting priority between operations inside the queue.

Comment: I haven't worked much with NSOperationQueues. I do more with dispatch queues, and I guess I lead you wrong based on an incorrect read of the docs. Try `setThreadPriority:` instead.

Comment: Tried to set the thread priority to 0.1, but to UI still no response while running the operation... :(

Comment: setThreadPriority: takes a double between 0 and 1, so using NSOperationQueuePriority values won't work (they range between -8 and +8)